# Separate git directories (master/dev)

Tags: git

I work locally in one directory with my source code. I've got two branches : master and dev. I want to push on my dedicated server each branch to its own directory, resulting one directory for production and another for developpement. Next, I can configure Nginx for accessing each one on subdomains, etc.

I tried to use this code, on post-receive file in my (only) project.git/hooks/post-receive.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`

  if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/home/myself/project/site --git-dir=/home/myself/myproject/myproject.git checkout -f
    echo 'Changes pushed live.'
  fi

  if [ "dev" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/home/myself/myproject/site-dev --git-dir=/home/myself/myproject/myproject.git checkout -f
    echo 'Changes pushed to dev.'
  fi
done
```

I try to commit changes for dev branch. I push it successfully ("Changes pushed to dev"). But dev directory has not been changed at all on my remote server (same as master branch).

Could you help me please ?

Thanks !

Comment: Git is not a release tool. You can use it for release stuff, but it won't work well. I'd suggest you look into a release tool instead.

Comment: Indeed. You should have release process *pulling* from your repository whenever there are changes, not the other way around. This will continue to bite you in multiple different ways.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll go to the classic way (push and pull on the directory) :)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments. Git is not really a deploy tool. You should have git-post-recv trigger the deploy-tool to do the actual deploy.

However, the deploy-script will look very similar to the hook you have above, and will probably exhibit the same issue. The part that appears to be missing is to actually choose the `dev` branch to be checked out in the `site-dev` directory. The command

```
git --work-tree=/home/myself/myproject/site-dev --git-dir=/home/myself/myproject/myproject.git checkout -f
```

will check out the current HEAD (typically master) there. Try adding `dev` to the checkout command.

You may also be interested to add a variation of `git clean -ffdx` to remove all files not known to git, so you have a pristine checkout.